# Batch-importing images in sync with audio/markers

Tags: premiere, workflow

I am trying to create a sequence that displays hundreds of images in succession. I want the images to change according to the speed/mood/beat of the music that plays at that moment. For example, changing to the next image every time the kickdrum is heard. I am talking about a rapid succession of images, many of them will only show for a couple of frames. So basically I am looking for a way to accomplish this as fast as possible.

This is what I've come up with.

- First, I'll listen to the song and edit my preferences so that in the "General" tab, the "Still Image Default Duration" is set to the number of frames that would best sync up with the tempo/beat of the song.
- Next I'll listen to the song again in the "Source" panel and whilst playing it I'll set markers using the m keyboard shortuct where I'll want the images to change. If necessary, I'll listen to it again at half-speed or zooming in a lot and fine-tune the position of the markers until I am happy.
- Then I'll import the song to my timeline, along with all of my images, which of course will not be in sync with the markers. So I'll basically use the "Ripple Edit Tool" with all of my images, and individually set the in and out points of every single image so that they 'snap' to the markers.
- Finally I'll fine-tune again the in and out points of the images, performing ripple deletes and doing minor adjustments.

Is there a way to speed up this workflow? Maybe a way so that when I import all of the images to the timeline, they'll sync automatically their in and out points with the position of the markers?

Thanks. I'm using Adobe Premiere Pro CS6.

Answer (score 1):

You are going along the right track, but the first step is not necessary.  You want to use the "automate to sequence" functionality, found under the Project menu, to set the images to the markers.  There are a variety of orders that you can have it insert the images in and you may need to do some adjustments to how you bring in the images to make them go in the correct order, but it will handle setting the start and end points at the markers and can even automate transitions if you so desire.